# My lighter fell into the hole at the handbrake

Tags: ford, fiesta

my lighter fell into the hole at the handbrake and I cannot see it in order to remove it, will this cause any damage if I drive the car?

Answer (score 2):

Probably not, most likely it will find some cavity and remain there for the life of the vehicle. However it is full of fuel, if it were get close to a heat source the results could be bad.

Often handbrake covers are removable, it depends on the car how much work it would be. You could try and use a magnetic pick-up tool to retrieve it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, maybe not.. there can be lots of space under there and it can land somewhere harmless.

It can also land, or move during driving, at a point where it could be crushed, so it is best to find it.